# How to maintain "while" cycle in Python?

Tags: python, sql

I'm in need of simple python script, that will fetch data from MSSQL database on a trigger and then send it to Telegram. My problem is that I cannot write appropriate while cycle to hold it until the SQL trigger works. Here's the code

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(server='serv', user='user', password='pwd', database='DB')
cursor = conn.cursor()
print('connection success')
# Select Query
print('Reading data from table')
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
   
    row = str(0)
    while row == 0:
        cursor.execute("""
            CREATE TRIGGER Server_enter
            ON pLogData
            AFTER INSERT
                   AS SELECT [TimeVal],[Remark],[Name],[FirstName]
                                 FROM [data1]
                                 INNER JOIN [data2]
                                    ON [ID]=[ID]
                                    WHERE [Remark] LIKE '%server%' """)
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        print(str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]) + " " + str(row[2]) + " " + str(row[3]))
```

Now its writing me "reading data from table" and Process finished.
How to make appropriate cycle?

Comment: You're setting `row = str(0)` and then checking `row == 0`. This will be false and your loop will never execute. `"0" != 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you're setting up your loop. You have:

```
row = str(0)
while row == 0:
    # code
```

however, the string `"0"` is not equal to the integer `0`, so the loop will never execute and will be skipped.

You will hit a similar issue on subsequent iterations as `fetchone` doesn't return `0` when no data is available, it returns `None`. You should be basing the loop condition on that:

```
row = None
while row is None:
```